Output noise of integrator op amp
Consider the following circuit (https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_6.html)

I want to compute the output noise of the op amp.
I believe the op-amp noise is given by the quadratic sum of the IR noise (current x resistance) referred to the input, the thermal noise of the resistances and capacitor referred to the input, and the voltage noise referred to the input, all of them multiplied by the op-amp gain, which in this case is frequency dependent.
Can anyone confirm my analysis, I have doubts about the input impedance that I should take into account and the way I handle the gain:
$$
V_{n, R_1,RTI} = \sqrt{4 k T R_1 \Delta f}
$$
$$
V_{n, R_2,RTI} = \sqrt{4 k T R_2 \Delta f}/A(f)
$$
where the gain \$A(f)\$ is
$$
A(f) = -\frac{R_2}{R_1} \times \frac{1}{1 + 2 \pi f C R_2}
$$
I neglect the thermal noise of the capacitor.
The RTI current x resistance noise is the input current density noise (which is given in the op amp spec sheet as a function of frequency) multiplied by the input impedance:
$$
V_{n, i_n} = i_n \cdot R_{input}
$$
with the input impedance \$R_{input}= R_1//(R2//C)\$
The voltage noise \$(V_{n, op\_amp,RTI}\$) is also given in the op amp spec sheet as a function of frequency (input voltage noise density).
The total output noise (\$V_{n, total}\$) is the root sum square of all individual noise sources:
$$
V_{n, total}(out) = \sqrt{(V_{n, R_1,RTI}A(f) )^2 + (V_{n, R_2,RTI}A(f) )^2 + (V_{n, op\_amp,RTI}A(f) )^2  + V_{n, i_n}A(f) )^2 }
$$

This sort of circuit has noise dominated by internal opamp noise. Please explain where you have factored this into your derivation. I mean, I can't see it.

@Andyaka, I am not sure what you are talking about, I am a beginner. What is the internal op amp noise you refer to? I know about input current noise and voltage noise, is it something else? If you don't see it, I probably have not put it

@DarkBulle You are doing noise analysis for everything else but have an ideal noiseless opamp. If you have some real world op-amp you can buy, it may have noise characteristics in the data sheet of that component.

@Justme, okay I will try to figure this out, I think you are saying the same think Andy is

@DarkBulle, I recommend this paper https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/apn/r13an0010-noise-calculations-op-amp-circuits?language=en
